# ViewRendererServlet vs Dispatcherservlet Difference

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What are the applications of `DispatcherServlet` versus `ViewRendererServlet` in Spring MVC? Are they related in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DispatcherServlet is the front controller front door to your application.  You always use that, but it'll be via configuration.

Likewise, view resolvers for JSPs, Velocity, etc. are used in configuration.  You probably won't write code to invoke them.

Comment: Then when are we going to use ViewRendererServlet , since it will also act as a front controller. @duffymo

Comment: It dones not act as a front controller servlet; that's the DispatcherServlet.  It examines incoming requests and routes them to handlers for processing ViewResolvers reconcile next views once the processing is done and the next view is determined.  They're separate.